# data stored on an angular service appears to not be persistant

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use ng-show to set up page navigation by showing or hiding the appropriate div tags

I managed to get it to work but then realized that i didn't know how to trigger "pageChange()" from other controllers.

After some googling I learned about services.

So, I now have a service that stores the page variable which can be changed by other controllers.

The problem is that it seems to be resetting itself to whatever i use to initialise it. I'm not sure why or how to fix it.

service:

```
app.service('navigationService', function() {
    var pa = this; //pa for parent
    this.page;

    this.changePage = function(p){
        //p is the new page
        pa.page = p
        console.log(pa.page);

    };
});
```

NavigationController:

```
app.controller("navCon", ["$scope", "navigationService", function($scope, navigationService){
    var conNav = this;
    this.page = navigationService.page;  
    navigationService.changePage("login"); //initialising the service page variable as "login" also does not work

    this.digest = function(){//display something whenever a digest cycle is run

        console.log(conNav.page);
    }
}]);
```

When i run the page, the log looks like this:

```
login
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

Not sure it's relevant but this is where the page is shown/hidden and where the 'digest' function is called:

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-show="{{nav.page == 'home'}}">
    <div class="row" ng-class="{'go':nav.digest()}"><!--go is not really a class but this is the only way i know how to trigger a function with every digest-->
```

I am fairly new to angular and have no idea where i'm going wrong, so if anybody can see why it page becomes 'undefined' after the first log please let me know how to fix.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My main problem here was that the changes to the service didn't appear to be persistent. I later learned that the service WAS persistent but the controller wasn't updating.

so i made the following changes:

- in navcon i added a watch
- moved some lines about to register the watch after the variable was initialized
- I then called the `changePage` method from the service

  ```
  this.page = "login";
  $scope.$watch(function(){ return navigationService.page;}, function(){
      console.log("service changed");
      conNav.page = navigationService.page;
      })

  navigationService.changePage("login");
  ```

Then (I'm not sure why) I had to change the `ng-show` directives to `ng-if`.

and NOW the navigation works.

thanks to everyone for helping

Answer (score 2):

I am hoping you are using controller as syntax here as you are using `this` to access controller instance

Problem in your case is you are accessing

```
navigationService.page
```

before setting it up using

```
navigationService.changePage("login")
```

So call the service method first and then access the service property.

Comment: That fixed the "undefined" problem, however if i now add 'navigationService.changePage("home")' to a 'doLogin' function attatched to a button on the login page, i get 'home' 'login' 'login' in the console, which i just realised suggests the problem is with 'this.page' not updating

Answer (score 1):

you can listen $stateChange events in your controller, and then call your service function

Comment: Okay, So i googled this and added a $watch that updated the navCon's page variable. However The page doesn't change to "home" when it should... I don't think the expression is being evaluated at the ng-show, any suggestions?

Comment: In my opinion, for what you are trying to do, what I understand is that you're trying to hide the menu when a navigation happens, right? If yes, then I suggest you to use a controller which listens stateChanges, and mutate a visibility parameter that decides what you show in ng-show.

Comment: In addition, usage of $scope and "this" in the controller at the same time may cause malfunctionality. Either use "controllers as" and "this", or just $scope, and don't use $digest function when you really need it to use. Angular uses it for you on changes

Comment: the digest wasn't the angular function, i just called it digest so i remembered what it was. I was basically making an angular equivelant of jQuery's `data-page` attribute, so all my "pages" are just divs and angular shows/hides them as needed. Seeing as i don't appear to need `$scope`, I have removed it, thanks for the warning. in response to your suggestion, I have posted the solution in the answer above. Thanks for your help :)